# Spring 3.0 EL How to get property from a properties file?

Tags: java, spring

Using Spring 3.0 EL can we auto wire a property from a property file to a component?

I know we can load a properties file using `Util` namespace and we can access it as a bean, but can we autowire using spring EL.

`<util:properties id="myProperties" location="/WEB-INF/my.properties"/>`

Comment: Can you give an example of what sort of thing would be wired up?

Comment: I assume to a `String ` property

Comment: I guess spring EL can convert the property to the required type too. For example I have a property like `min.age.required=18` in my properties file. And I want to wire this to `int age;` in my service. How to do it using EL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@Value("#{ myProperties['min.age.required'] }")
int age;
```

By the way, good old `<context:property-placeholder .../>` works fine too:

```
@Value("${min.age.required}")
int age;
```